# Multiple accounts on iOS Developer Program

Tags: ios, app-store, account

My company develops Apps for different clients say ClientA, ClientB, and ClientC. I already have my company's iOS developer program setup and have Apps for ClientA. Now I want to develop an Apps for ClientB and ClientC, and want to keep their App selling and Bank accounts separate. If I create new iOS developer programs, when people clicks more Apps from this Developer, it won't displayed ClientA, ClientB and ClientC all together. Am I right? Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Client B and Client C will require their own accounts which you could use to publish their apps on their behalf

Comment: ...but it's my company developing apps for them!! How would I list the number of apps developed by my company then. Users have to search for individual clients?

Comment: @applefreak Its a client project so whether you code it or some one else does, it is their project. If you want to share that you have done this then you can add the project links with client feed back

Comment: Hi Rohan, it's client but we are in 50% partnership so I am going to monitor all accounts and they all will belongs to me. I just want to keep separate because of the payments. I don't want to get all payments in same bank account and them distributes based on number of apps sold for each clients.

Comment: Apple does not recognize partnerships (Unless you incorporate your partnership into one company owned 50% by both and enroll that one company in the developer program).  You have to choose either one individual or one company account for each app.

Answer (score 1):

You must be create new Apple Developer Account for clientB and clientC. and publish your app with this new account.

Comment: ...but it's my company developing apps for them!! How would I list the number of apps developed by my company then. Users have to search for individual clients?

Comment: You can only list by one individual or one company (the developer account used to submit the app).  So you have to choose one company for each app.  The only way to change this listing is to transfer the app between accounts.

Answer (score 1):

When user **clicks more Apps from this Developer**, it'll display the name of the app's **provision profile's developer account** only.

if you want to list the number of apps developed by your company means, Open one developer account with our company name and use in your company app.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the bank accounts for each client's app separate, then you have to use a separate iOS developer account for each client, and you can not list apps under your own individual name.  Apple does not recognize non-incorporated partnerships, only individuals and companies.

Choose one or the other.  (Or forget developing for Apple's iOS App store).